# Does GKE Ingress-GCE support compression?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

My backend, in Rocket (Rust), does not have compression built in. So, it is dependent on the proxy to compress it. Though nginx ingress controller supports it, I thought whether the default one had it too as it has high availability.

If it does not have, then how should I setup?

Comment: Are you referring to HTTP compression such as gzip or deflate?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to.

Comment: please see the updated answer. It looks like GCLB supports GZIP, but nginx get confused because of the Via header and it disables GZIP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE(2018-01-31):**  It looks like Cloud HTTP(S) Load Balancer **supports** GZIP. You just have to serve compressed content from your backend and the load balancer will pass it on.

However, NGINX is confused because of the `Via` header (it thinks proxies don't support GZIP, and on most cloud providers this is correct, but not Google). See this FAQ: https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/troubleshooting#compression-not-working

> If you are using the nginx web server software, modify the nginx.conf
>   configuration file to enable compression. The location of this file
>   depends on where nginx is installed. In many Linux distributions, the
>   file is stored at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. To allow nginx compression to
>   work with HTTP(S) load balancing, add the following two lines to the
>   http section of nginx.conf:
>
> ```
> gzip_proxied any;
> gzip_vary on;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I believe nginx does not compress requests via a proxy by default.

You can change its config to enable that:

`gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;`

Source: https://blog.percy.io/tuning-nginx-behind-google-cloud-platform-http-s-load-balancer-305982ddb340