# gzip in gke with nginx-ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gzip, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to configure gzip to work in a python application that runs on a kubernetes with nginx-ingress in GKE. But I discovered that it is no use to enable gzip in the ingress-controller config-map because I need to enable compression on the backend as I understand it.

How can I enable compression on the backend of my python application to run gzip on nginx controller?

My main problem is that searching here in stackoverflow I know I need to put the compression in the backend, just do not know how to do this.

Comment: What's not clear is what data you want to compress the packets which server sends to clients or content within the pods?

Comment: This is previously discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039952/does-gke-ingress-gce-support-compression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does GKE Ingress-GCE support compression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039952/does-gke-ingress-gce-support-compression)

Comment: @RaunakJhawar I want to compress the packets which server sends to clients.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google So this discussion is what has to be done, my point is that I do not understand how it should be done. 
I did not find any documentation on how to set up a backend with compressed content. I found some libs for my application to already send compressed, but it would be a problem to apply why I would need to put a lib in all my classes and that application is still a legacy monolithic.

Comment: @JonatasOliveira have you managed to solve your question? As you said that you want to configure compression from `server` -> `clients` by server you mean your `python app`? Could you share the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your `app` and your `nginx-ingress` version for a reproduction purposes?

Answer (score 12):

Focusing specifically on the title of this question and extending on the example of such setup as pointed by user @Raunak Jhawar.

You can configure your `nginx-ingress` to compress the data by updating the `ingress-nginx-controller` **configmap**.

This would work on the path:

- `Pod` ----> `NGINX Ingress controller` - **`GZIP`** -> `Client` (Web browser)

To enable such setup you will need to edit the `Ingress` controller configmap like below:

- `$ kubectl edit configmap -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller`

```yaml
data: # ADD IF NOT PRESENT
  use-gzip: "true" # ENABLE GZIP COMPRESSION
  gzip-types: "*" # SPECIFY MIME TYPES TO COMPRESS ("*" FOR ALL)
```

You can find more reference and options to configure by following below link:

- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress NGINX: User guide: Nginx-configuration: Configmap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/)*

> **A side note!**
>
> You can also use other methods of editing resources like: `$ kubectl patch`

This changes would make the `nginx-ingress-controller` Pod to be automatically reconfigured.

I've included an example of such setup below.

---

To check if the compression occurs and if it's working I've used following setup:

- `NGINX Ingress Controller` spawned by:

  - *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress NGINX: Deploy: GCE-GKE](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke)*
- `NGINX` pod with a `5mb.txt` file filled with **`0`**'s
- `Service` and `Ingress` resource that will expose the `NGINX` pod with `NGINX Ingress Controller`

You can check if your setup with `nginx-ingress` supoorts `gzip` compression by either:

- Checking with `Developer tools` with a browser of your choosing:

  - `Chrome` -> `F12` -> `Network` -> Go to site (or refresh) and press on example file (look on `Response Header`):

  [image: RESPONSE HEADER]
- You can also use `curl` command like below ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9140223/12257134)):

  - `$ curl $URL$ --silent --write-out "%{size_download}\n" --output /dev/null` - get size **without** compression
  - `$ curl $URL$ --silent -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" --write-out "%{size_download}\n" --output /dev/null` - get the size **with** compression (if supported)

Above methods have shown the compression rate of about `99%` (`5MB` file compressed to `50KB`)

---

I also encourage you to check below links for additional reference:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: How can I tell if my server is serving GZipped content?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9140223/12257134)*
- *[Serverfault.com: Gzip compression with nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/496098/gzip-compression-with-nginx)*
   - link about images (I have learned the hard way)

Answer (score 3):

This makes this as a nginx conversation. There are a lot of docs available which guides on hows and whats with nginx compression. Essentially, you have to add a bunch of gzip related settings and options in your nginx configuration file.

The tread shared above is a good starter and shows exactly what needs to be on the nginx conf. Please note that, as a good practice, do not compress any/all inbound packets as this essentially adds more compute burden on the CPU. The nginx conf has one option to only compress packets which exceed certain size.

Comment: Hi, this is correct and I believe you have also restarted your nginx service.

Comment: Hello @Raunak Jhawar I'm using the gzip config in my nginx-controller config map: 
`
 gzip on;
 gzip_comp_level 5;
 gzip_http_version 1.1;
 gzip_min_length 256;
 gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/css text/plain text/x-component;
 gzip_proxied any;
 gzip_vary on;
 `

Comment: I'm recreate my pod, but the header not found gzip. In the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039952/does-gke-ingress-gce-support-compression talk about compress backend to found gzip in GKE.